# PHP Copy all files/folders from one directory to another

Tags: php, copy

I'm trying to get a "reset" script working in PHP to essentially just copy all files/folders from one specific directory to another.

I've found plenty of snippets of code on Stackoverflow for recursively copying files/folders but I cannot get any of them to work.

My directory essentially looks like:

```
/public_html/folder1/reset.php
/public_html/folder1/files/
/public_html/docs/reset/files/
```

The `reset.php` file is the file I am trying to get working and I want to copy all of the files from `/docs/reset/files/` over to `/folder1/files/` overwriting everything...

I've tried the following code but it generates a 500mb~ file full of errors

```
<?php 
function recurse_copy($src,$dst) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 
    @mkdir($dst); 
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
}

recurse_copy("../docs/reset/", "/")

?>
```

The code does appear to be cycling through correctly but the paths are all wrong.

`[18-Jun-2020 07:54:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  copy(/files//files/copies/index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/USERNAME/public_html/folder1/reset.php on line 11`

If I could get the above working I was going to try the following:

```
$src = '/full/path/to/src'; // or relative path if so desired 
$dst = '/full/path/to/dst'; // or relative path if so desired
$command = 'cp -a ' . $src . ' ' .$dst;
$shell_result_output = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd($command));
```

As I assume that would be faster?

I must be doing something wrong and I'm sure it's going to be something really minor but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So you get 500MB worth of error messages logged, but you don’t feel like sharing any of those.

Comment: @CBroe My bad, I thought I had copied one in. I just updated the post. You can see the path is wrong